# How to group a data into n groups with minimal sum within a group and minimal variance across groups

Tags: r

here is my data. I would like to group them into ten groups. with a minimal sum of var1 within-group and minimal variance of var2 across groups.

```r
data <- data.frame(id=1:100,var1=runif(1000),var2=runif(1000))
```

Comment: You want minimal variance of var2 across groups. Meaning you want a high within-group variance (the opposite of what [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) does)?

Comment: I have two variables for groups.  I want minimal variance of means of var2  across groups. in addition, I should have a minimal sum of var1 within each group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to understand the minimal sum of var1 condition, as the total sum will always be the same. I have assumed it means to have the lowest maximum group sum.

```r
# Create dataset
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(var1 = runif(1000), var2 = runif(1000))

# Create 50 splits
# These are numerically balanced by var2 as specified
# meaning that groups will have similar means
data_grouped <- data %>% 
  groupdata2::fold(k = 10,
                   num_col = "var2",
                   num_fold_cols = 50)

# Find the split with the lowest maximum sum of a group
data_grouped %>% 
  # Note that `gather()` will lead to 50k rows
  # So might need to rethink this step for a bigger dataset
  tidyr::gather(key = "split", value = "group", 3:52) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(split, group) %>% 
  # Find sum per group per split
  dplyr::summarise(var1_sum = sum(var1), .groups = "drop_last") %>% 
  # Find max group sum per split
  dplyr::summarise(var1_max = max(var1_sum)) %>% 
  # Find split with lowest max group sum
  dplyr::filter(var1_max == min(var1_max))

> # A tibble: 1 x 2
>   split     var1_max
>   <chr>        <dbl>
> 1 .folds_19     51.9

# Assign best grouping factor to original data frame
data$group <- data_grouped$.folds_19

# Check the means of var2
data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(var2_mean = mean(var2))

> # A tibble: 10 x 2
>    group var2_mean
>    <fct>     <dbl>
>  1 1         0.491
>  2 2         0.489
>  3 3         0.490
>  4 4         0.490
>  5 5         0.492
>  6 6         0.490
>  7 7         0.489
>  8 8         0.491
>  9 9         0.491
> 10 10        0.490
```